# Django admin: many-to-one relationships and creation of new "many" object from existing "one"

Tags: django

**Django==1.11.5**

I have two models:

```
class Sheet(models.Model):
    canonical_image = models.ForeignKey('images.Image',
                                   blank=True,
                                   null=True,
                                   on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                   related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related", 
                                   verbose_name=_("canonical image"))


class Image(models.Model):

    sheet = models.ForeignKey(Sheet,
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                              verbose_name=_("sheet"))
    pass
```

I registered the models for Django admin.

Now when I change the sheet in admin, I see "Canonical image" and a plus button to add an image.

If I press the plus button, a form for creating a new Image appear.
And there is going to be a drop down list with choices sheets. There is a bunch of sheets there.

This is clumsy. I press a plus sign from a definite sheet. That very sheet should be selected for creation a new image.

Could you tell me how to cope with this problem. Maybe to limit the choice to that particular sheet. Or remove the sheet from image creation form and substitute it in input type="hidden".

Or something else. The easier the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment, but I do not have enough points for that.

But have you looked into creating a `ModelAdmin`?
[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

In a `ModelAdmin` class, you can also add inlines for other model, which either links to the model you attach the `ModelAdmin` to, or models that your current model links to.

Comment: What makes you think they don't already have an inline? The problem described is when clicking through to create a new `canonical_image` for a Sheet.

Comment: You might be right, but I would need the question to be more concrete as to what the state of the project is, and what exactly is needed.

Comment: Shawnse, thank you for the kick. I don't have inlines so fare. I have found the example in the tutorial. Hope, it helps.